# Optimizing the area covered by a fixed set of polygons

Tags: python, optimization, dynamic-programming, shapely

I'm trying to use the python package `shapely` to tackle the following problem. I have a fixed rectangle(say R), which is a "boundary" and inside it, there is a fixed collection of sub-rectangles(say `P_1, ..., P_n`). I also have a fixed collection of rectangles(say `A_1, ..., A_n`). Here the blue rectangle is the boundary and the red ones are the fixed sub-rectangles.

[image: polygons]

Here's the problem: I wish to cover the blue rectangle, by filling it up with the rectangles `A_i`s such that they do not intersect with each other, nor with the sub-rectangles in such a way that the area covered is maximized (or close enough is also good). I have no idea how to approach this problem any suggestions on how to proceed will be very helpful.

Comment: `I have no idea how to approach this problem` this tells me that you don't have a program design in mind; you seem to want to simultaneously design *and* implement this. I think you should separate those two concepts, and just focus on fully designing your program before trying to implement. Once you run into implementation detail issues, then StackOverflow can help, but this is general and isn't really about actual code, which is this site's exclusive focus. Maybe you could ask about the design on a more math or geometry-focused StackExchange site? Your post might get more attention that way.

Comment: There is a stackexchange for mathematics. That might be a good place to go and ask for an algorithm to approach this problem.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.